# body height does not fill page

Tags: html, css, height

I have tried to set 100% height on the body, it works if there is no content, but with content the body does not fill the page.

```
<html>
 <body>
 test body
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
     <div class="item"> asdasdasda sda sda sdas das d</div>
</body>
```

```
html {
    background: red;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: white;
    max-width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.item {
    height: 150px;
}
```

I am getting MAD!

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/02dknpeo/2/

Comment: I checked. It works.

Comment: You can add `overflow:hidden;` to see it works.

Comment: just remove height. set min-height to 100%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the body stays the height of the page, regardless if the content is overflowing or not.
 Use [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) so it will be the pages height if the content isn't taller then the window, but will grow to fit the content if it is:

```
body {
    background: white;
    max-width: 320px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bv1aaub6/

Comment: Thank you for the solution! it was not working with my code so I have find out that was caused by floating divs. This solution would not work if there are floating divs in the body so I had to replace the float with flex.... unbelievable.

Comment: @MaRco85 trick with float, you can just set their parents overflow to hidden, in your case `body{overflow:hidden;}`, and the parent will grow to fit them

Answer (score 2):

Change the `height` of `100%` on the `body` element to a [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) instead:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uyy2ustm/)

In doing so, the `body` element will always have *at least* a height of `100%` rather than always having a height of `100%` of the window (which is what your problem was).

```
body {
    background: white;
    max-width: 320px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! it was not working with my code so I have find out that was caused by floating divs. This solution would not work if there are floating divs in the body so I had to replace the float with flex.... unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

You're restricting the height of the body element to the height of the viewport. Don't.

```
body {
    /* height: 100% */
}
```

If you need it to be at least that high, use `min-height`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/02dknpeo/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for the solution! it was not working with my code so I have find out that was caused by floating divs. This solution would not work if there are floating divs in the body so I had to replace the float with flex.... unbelievable.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `height:100%` from the body rule.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/02dknpeo/4/)**

Comment: Thank you for the solution! it was not working with my code so I have find out that was caused by floating divs. This solution would not work if there are floating divs in the body so I had to replace the float with flex.... unbelievable.